# Add more graphs to the base dashboard in Chronograf

Tags: debian, influxdb, telegraf, chronograf

I would like to know how to add more graphs to the initial dashboard for hosts in Chronograf? I have defined some custom data from 'input.exec' and I would like to be shown when entering the host main dasboard. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to create new layouts, or "precanned dashboards", for Chronograf.

You can use the `new_apps.sh` script in the `canned` directory to generate the necessary corresponding `.json` file(s) within the `/canned` directory.

Once these are created, Chronograf should include those new layouts as precanned dashboards.

The full documentation for how to do this can be found at: https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/blob/master/docs/LAYOUT.md.